# ImageIO.read results null

Tags: java, null, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Need help. I am doing a program which is combining pictures into one. I am using the Sample Pictures of Windows for my testing and it works fine. My problem is, I have an image which results to NullPointerException. Here's my code.

```
int imageHeight = 0;  
List<Integer> widthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> chunkHeight = new ArrayList<Integer>();

File[] imgFiles = new File[chunks]; 
for (int x = 0; x < chunks; x++) {  
    imgFiles[x] = new File(tempDirectory + newFileName + (x + 1) + ".png");
} 

BufferedImage[] buffImages = new BufferedImage[chunks];
for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {  
    buffImages[i] = ImageIO.read(imgFiles[i]);
    chunkHeight.add(buffImages[i].getHeight());
    imageHeight = imageHeight + buffImages[i].getHeight();
    widthList.add(buffImages[i].getWidth());
}
```

I encountered the NullPointer problem in getHeight() of the BufferedImage. My only finding in this is when I open the image in Photoshop, I got the error "Could not  complete your request because the file-format module cannot parse the file.". Thanks.

Edit:
Here's my link to image I used : http://www.mediafire.com/download/5bx322a08c29uae/image2.png

Comment: The image cannot be parsed by photsohop. Are you sure its an image file ?

Comment: yes, I think. I can open and view the image, and can also edit in Paint.

Comment: There is something wrong with the images, replace them with a set of new images and retry

Comment: I cant replace it with new images, it was user/customer who will upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the error "Could not complete your request because the
>   file-format module cannot parse the file."

As you say it can be a corrupt file. Just to check I did some tests like changed the .txt file to .png and I run this code.

```
BufferedImage b = null;
try {
    b = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\uysers\\Desktop\\so.png"));
    System.out.println(b.getHeight());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the below line had no problems

```
b = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\uysers\\Desktop\\so.png"));
```

whereas this line

`System.out.println(b.getHeight());` I got a nullpointer exception. So I would say you have a corrupt image file which makes the bufferred image null.

Comment: I can't say it is a corrupted file because I can open and view the image but not in Photoshop. thanks!

Comment: kindly try this file. thanks. http://www.mediafire.com/download/5bx322a08c29uae/image2.png

Comment: After a long workout I got to know that your image has a different format than (.png). Some results showed me tif or tiff type. But anyways if you open the image in paint and save it in a different format you will get the result for sure. All the best

Comment: My problem with this is, I can't control the file that being uploaded, it was the user/customer that can upload the image. Thanks to your answer, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIO.read` returns `null` if it doesn't recognize the file format. This is the documented behavior, so you should always test for `null` return values from `ImageIO.read`.

This is why you get the `NullpointerException` when asking for the height/width.

As Photoshop can't read it either, it most likely isn't a PNG file, or the file is corrupt.

You can easily fix your code by using:

```
List<BufferedImage> buffImages = new ArraysList<>(chunks);
for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {  
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgFiles[i]);

    if (image != null) {
        buffImages.add(image);
        chunkHeight.add(image.getHeight());
        imageHeight = imageHeight + image.getHeight();
        widthList.add(image.getWidth());
    }
}
```

PS: My Windows sample image folder only contains JPEGs, maybe you could post a link to the broken image?

Comment: I already post the link of the image at my first post. thanks!

Comment: I uploaded it to mediafire. can you check it? thanks